# .drop() function in pandas module returns a key error

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I imported pandas into a jupyter notebook environment and read data from a CSV file using the block of code below:

```
import pandas as pd
air_data = pd.read_csv("Data/air_data.csv")
air_data
```

I am trying to drop the `Dest_airport` column using the code snippet below:

```
new_air_data = air_data.drop(columns=["Dest_airport"])
new_air_data
```

But each time I run the code I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "['Dest_airport'] not found in axis"
```

However, if I execute the `drop()` function on the first column from the left it works successfully, but if I try it on any other column an error occurs.

What I have tried:

- reinstalling anaconda and jupyter notebook
- `new_air_data = air_data.drop(columns = ["Dest_airport"], axis = 1)` (I still end up with the same error)

See the full [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IquMk.jpg) and [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGDyT.jpg) for better inspection.

Comment: Could you put in a couple of lines of the data so we can understand the problem

Comment: can you print `air_data.columns`?

Comment: Open the code and error message image @Paul Brennan

Comment: Do not post errors, code, or data as images. They should be posted as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). That said, try `air_data.columns = air_data.columns.str.strip()` and then try to drop the column. There is probably leading or trailing whitespace.